# Grepping Columns and then Pasting to another file

Tags: file, grep, multiple-columns

Hey guys so I have a grep problem. I want to grep lines from a file that contain a certain number, and then I want to paste certain columns from that line to a file.

For example, if I have the number 1068

```
File A has 
1094   A   B  C
1068   D   E  F
1044   G   H  I

File B has
1092   L   M  N
1068   X   Y  Z
1045   Q   R  S

File C has 
1093   A   B  C
1062   D   E  F
1041   G   H  I
```

I want to grep the line that has 1068 from all files, only paste certain columns, and paste them side by side. Note that File C does not have 1068, but I would like to paste NA instead. So that the final output looks like this:

1068 FileA A C FileB X Z FileC NA NA

Any help would be appreciated! I don't now how you would grep columns, or even check if it exists. For example in File C, grep would just come out with nothing, but I want to had in NA NA instead. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a job for `grep`. More of an `awk` job.

```
awk -v num=1068 '
  BEGIN { printf "%d", num }

  # If file has changed and num has not been found...
  FNR==1 && NR!=1 && !found_num { printf " %s NA NA", FILENAME }

  # If at the beginning of a file (needs to be after previous line).
  FNR==1 { found_num = 0 }

  # If we find num, print the data and set found_num flag.
  $1 == num { printf " %s %s %s", FILENAME, $2, $4; found_num = 1 }

  END { if (!found_num) printf " %s NA NA", FILENAME; print"" }
' FileA FileB FileC
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. I'm in the process of writing a script, just because the problem was a little more complicated than I thought it would be, but thank you so much!

Comment: @user3799576 don't forget accepting the answer, if it solved your problem